How to Mock Nested queries in prisma test
I'm working with Prisma in an end-to-end test environment, and I'm trying to mock a connect operation to link a Product to an existing Category. Here’s the structure of my Prisma models:
model Product {
  id                 String            @id @map("_id")
  category_id        String
  category           Category          @relation(fields: [category_id], references: [id])
  // other fields

  @@map("products")
}

model Category {
  id               String            @id @map("_id")
  products         Product[]
  // other fields

  @@map("categories")
}

In my test, I’m attempting to create a new Product and connect it to a Category using prisma.product.create. Here’s the query:
prisma.product.create({
  data: {
    id: '1',
    // other data fields
    category: {
      connect: {
        id: category_id
      }
    }
  }
});

However, I keep getting this error:
 An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. No 'Category' record(s) (needed to inline the relation on 'Product' record(s)) was found for a nested connect on one-to-many relation 'CategoryToProduct'.

It seems like Prisma is unable to find the Category record, causing the connect operation to fail. I want to mock this nested query to simulate the existence of a Category so that connect doesn’t throw an error.
I tried mocking findUnique and all other finds on the Category model like this, but it didn’t resolve the issue:
prisma.category.findUnique.mockResolvedValue(categoryMockData);

Question: How can I mock the nested connect operation in Jest to prevent this "record not found" error?
